# Send a JSON object to the controller Codeigniter

Tags: json, codeigniter

I had a problem. When I try to send my JSON data to the controller and try to use it there I just got an empty array. I checked the XHR and my post is not empty but somehow the controller doesn't like it. :) 
In my view:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "http://www.domain.hu/bet/placebet/",
    data : "{'places':'" + JSON.stringify(arr) + "'}",
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(msg) {
        alert("Good");
    },
    fail : function(msg) {
        alert("Bed");
    }
});
```

And in my controller:

```
public function placebet() {
    $places = $this->input->post('places'); 
    echo json_encode(array('places'=>$places));
    exit;
}
```

So far I got an empty record. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at your JSON output? You might have a few `'` too many... Also jQuery is actually quite fine if you just pass it an array..

Comment: Hi!
Yeah I checked that it looks fine to me.
JSON
places "["9","10"]"

I will try it just as a simple array.

Comment: Also you want `json_decode` in your controller, not **en**code.

Comment: As a simple array it also empty... json_decode waiting for a string not for an array. I post a Json array thats why I use encode first.

Comment: This is how it works `(client) => (Object) => json_encode => transport => (server) => json_decode => (object)`

Answer (score 0):

since you are sending through a JSON string, then accepting it in post, then re-encoding it that seems to me like it would cause an issue. Try json_decoding it as suggested or you might also try a

```
print_r(json_decode(array('places'=>$places));
```

since you are expecting an array back, **print_r** is the way to go.